# passing object for polymorphic lookup parameter in Rails find/where

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, where-clause, belongs-to, polymorphism

Let's say I have:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  #...
end
```

now I want to find all comments on Jim's photo:

```
@jims_photo = Photo.where(:of => "Jim")
@photo_comments = Comment.where(:commentable => @jims_photo)
```

this seems to not work in rails (Rails 3). The generated query seems to not expand the polymorphic object into commentable_id and commentable_type fields:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comments.commentable:
```

I'm new to ruby and rails so I might be using the paradigm incorrectly but my expectation was that rails automatically expands

```
:commentable => @jims_photo
```

to:

```
:commentable_id => @jims_photo.id, :commentable_type => @jims_photo.class.name
```

Comment: @jims_photo.comments doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be really safe with:

```
:commentable_id => @jims_photo.id, :commentable_type => @jims_photo.class.name
```

Then I'd recommend replacing `.class.name` with `.base_class` (you don't actually need the `name`: `to_s` returns `name` and will be called automatically).

The reason for this is that when ActiveRecord saves the `_type` for a polymorphic association it'll use `base_class` to ensure it's not saving a class which itself is a polymorphic one.

If you play with `store_full_sti_class` you'll probably have to take even more precautions.

I highly recommend looking at Rails' STI code, [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb).

Comment: What's base_class? I get NoMethodError: undefined method `base_class'

Comment: @fatuhoku [see here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html#method-i-base_class).

Answer (score 2):

The guides for Rails are one of the best so I'd suggest you start reading about [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

You class declarations looks OK and I'm assuming that you're migrations is as well. But just for the sake of it. Let's say it looks like this:

```
class CreateComment < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :commentable, :polymorphic => true
      # this is the equivalent of
      # t.integer :commentable_id
      # t.string  :commentable_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Not if you have a `Article` or `Photo` object and you want to get the comments for that object then Thilo's suggestion is right on. All you need to do is this: `@jims_photo.comments`

If, on the other hand, you have a an instance of the `Comment` model, you can get the parent like this: `@comment.commentable`. But if you want to get Jim's photo comments best to do it like that. Otherwise, you'd have to supply as arguments both the `:commentable_id` and `commentable_type`. I'm not aware of any finder that expands the polymorphic object into `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` fields for you.

But you can always create a class method for that:

```
def self.find_by_parent(parent)
  where(:commentable_id => parent.id, :commentable_type => parent.class.name)
end
```